# aiohttp not getting detected when installing openai package

Tags: python, pip

I have aiohttp installed already. Im on ubuntu linux. When I try to install the package this error pops up. what am i doing wrong? can anyone help me?

```
      l8d3ydhd/openai_1e37ea26d6f14dd187db87c3e373f465/openai/api_requestor.py", line 21, in <module>
          import aiohttp
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 1):

for anyone that has the same problem, just update your pip. idk why it was outdated.